# How could I detect the last line of a page in QWeb?

Tags: qweb, odoo-15

I'm working with QWeb and my problem comes from a `foreach` element. This `foreach` element takes fields (named `task-ids`) and writes them line-by-lines.
I want to add a footer with the company's picture and a margin on top so that the last `task_ids` of the page isn't too close to the picture.
It seems that when the program is running the `foreach`, it doesn't take in account the margin, and whichever method that I've tried, the text is always glued to the company's picture.

I tried to insert the style both in like that:

```
<div class="footer" style="height: 30%">
```

---

And like that:

```
<p style="margin-top: 50px">
...
Image stuff
...
</p>
```

But none of these methods seems to work.

---

One way I would have thought to do this is to detect when the `foreach` reaches the end of the page and place a `bottom_margin` there, is it the right solution, and, if it is, what would be the syntax ?